# Spring webclient connection reset by remote server, but not RestTemplate

Tags: spring, webclient, resttemplate

I have problem with Spring WebClient, the error is like reset conn by server. But when I replace with RestTemplate, the problem disappeared. Can any help?

```
2020-10-08T23:30:36.515+07:00|2|ERROR|global-spi-engine|2417bb1abef50e40,2417bb1abef50e40,true,|73700|reactor-http-nio-8|o.s.w.s.adapter.HttpWebHandlerAdapter|[5e52ab55] 500 Server Error for HTTP POST "/requests"
java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer
    at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.read0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_241]
    Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException: 
Error has been observed at the following site(s):
    |_ checkpoint ⇢ Request to GET https://*** [DefaultWebClient]
    |_ checkpoint ⇢ Handler com.ascendcorp.orbit.globalspiengine.service.api.controller.SpiController#call(Map, AbstractSPIRequestDTO) [DispatcherHandler]
    |_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.web.TraceWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    |_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.reactive.server.MetricsWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    |_ checkpoint ⇢ HTTP POST "/requests" [ExceptionHandlingWebHandler]
```

Comment: Looks like that your POST request doesn't have the request body as the server expected. Otherwise the web service could have a bug, if you believe that your request is correct.

Comment: Nope, "POST" is just a request I send to my endpoint GW, then it forward to the external endpoint based on the payload info: url, body, headers using Spring Flux WebClient. The webservice has no problem as I can call by CURL/Postman and Spring RestTemplate as the code not commented.

Comment: FYI, use Jetty for connector works. So problem lies around with the Netty httpClient